# Heroku Free Account

Tags: heroku, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have created a custom activity for marketing cloud by using free Heroku account but now client want to use that custom activity in production.
My question is
1.Is it possible to use heroku free account for lots of API call ?
2.How many request can send a heroku free account as per single app ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It doesn't sound like your question is very coding-related. You might reach more admins and MC experts at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your client is asking you to put this into production why aren't you using paid dynos and billing the client for them?

Comment: In any case, this might or might not be fine. It depends on the specific application and your actual needs. Going to sleep and having to wake up again might be an issue, but only _you_ can decide whether this is good enough. Try it and see.